# Multiple Datasources with the same model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I have several databases that will contain a structural clone of the same table, however each table will have different data. So essentially the model stays the same, only the datasource changes depending on a User or User Group. With Is there any way of getting around adding a connection in web.config for each datasource or is there a way I can just pass around server/database/usr/pw info?

Comment: There is nothing in your question that is MVC related, I have edited to make it more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

based on which datasource to engage you can pass the appropriate connection string

```
var db1Context = new DataSourceEntities("data source one conn string");
var db2Context = new DataSourceEntities("data source two conn string");
```

now if you have to hit first data source you can use `dbContext1`

```
 dbContext1.TableName.AddObject(object);
```

similarly for the second data source

you can add the conn strings in web.config and retrieve them like

```
var conn1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key1"].ToString();
var conn2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key2"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to store connection string information in the web.config at all.  Like 3nigma's answer, you can do it all in code.  You just pass a string witht he connection string info directly into it.  You can build a connection string using the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class to simplify this.